# Split array in array of arrays based on sum of attribute

Tags: python

I have an array with the following structure:

```
[('path1', 10), ('path2', 12), ('path3', 10), ('path4', 7), ('path5', 18)]
```

I want to split that array in a array of array based on sum of second parameter. I want to have a variable called `max_size` and when `max_size` is greater then 20, it should split and start a next list. The result should be something like that:

```
[(('path1', 10)), (('path2', 12)), (('path3', 10), ('path4', 7)), (('path5', 18))]
```

How i do that in python? I'm trying to write something like:

```
max_size = 0
    for i, obj in enumerate(temp):
    dfs = []
    for j, obj in enumerate(temp):
        if(max_size < 100):
            max_size = size + obj[1]
            dfs.append(pd.read_csv(obj[0]))
            temp.remove(obj)
            print obj[0]
        else:
            break;
    print i
    print "###" * 10       
    grouped.append(dfs)
```

But it's didn't work and i'm stuck.

What is the best to do it?

Comment: What if one element is larger than `max_size`, like `('path30',124)`?

Comment: It will not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
def group_by_sum(data, max_value):
    sum = 0
    start = 0
    result = []
    for i, t in enumerate(data):
        if sum + t[1] > max_value:
            result.append(data[start:i])
            start = i
            sum = 0
        sum += t[1]
    result.append(data[start:])
    return result

# Example
data = [('path1', 10), ('path2', 12), ('path3', 10), ('path4', 7), ('path5', 18)]
result = group_by_sum(data, 20)
print (result)
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/FyFv)

Answer (score 0):

Without making use of any libraries, you can do this with:

```
def group_threshold(data,max_size):
    result = []
    cur_size = 0
    cur_straight = []
    for datum in data:
        _,size = datum
        if cur_size+size > max_size:
            result.append(tuple(cur_straight))
            cur_straight = []
            cur_size = 0
        cur_size += size
        cur_straight.append(datum)
    result.append(tuple(cur_straight))
    return result
```

You can then call it with:

```
>>> data = [('path1', 10), ('path2', 12), ('path3', 10), ('path4', 7), ('path5', 18)] # the original data
>>> max_size = 20 # the size threshold
>>> group_threshold(data,max_size)
[(('path1', 10),), (('path2', 12),), (('path3', 10), ('path4', 7)), (('path5', 18),)]
```